# Не получается удалить первые три символа каждой строки, которые находятся в массиве строк

Tags: python

Вводится 5 строк, в которых сначала записан порядковый номер строки с точкой, а затем – слово. Вывести слова в алфавитном порядке. Проблема в том, что нужно отсортировать по не по номеру, а по алфавиту, это легко, но нужно удалить цифры, у меня не получается

```
s = [input () for i in range (5)]

for j in range (len(s)):
    s[j] = list(s[j])
    del s[j][0:2]

def quicksort (s):
    if len(s) == 1 or len(s) == 0 :
        return s
    pivot = s[0]
    less = [i for i in s[1:] if i <= pivot]
    greater = [i for i in s[1:] if i > pivot]
    return ''.join(quicksort (less)) + ''.join([pivot]) + ''.join(quicksort (greater))

print ((quicksort (s)))
```

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Как получаемый результат отличается от желаемого? Приведите пример входых данных, нужный результат и тот результат, который выдает ваш код.

Comment: `s[j] = s[j][3:]`

Comment: `s = [el[3:] for el in s]`

Comment: Работает для строк (которые введены без цифр), а например 1.Арбуз сортирует по цифре, а нужно ее удалить и отсортировать по буквам

Comment: s = [el[3:] for el in s] - работает, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [input () for i in range (5)]
s = [el[3:] for el in s]

def quicksort (s):
    if len(s) == 1 or len(s) == 0 :
        return s
    pivot = s[0]
    less = [i for i in s[1:] if i <= pivot]
    greater = [i for i in s[1:] if i > pivot]
    return quicksort (less) + [pivot] + quicksort (greater)

print (' '.join (quicksort (s)))
```